# Swap two entire vectors/queue/stack time cost?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

For example:

```
v1 = {1,2,3},    v2 = {4,5};
swap(v1, v2);
```

now `v1 = {4,5}`,   `v2 = {1,2,3}`

I think it should be very fast with no regards of the length of these two vectors right? It's just swapping pointers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. > I think it should be very fast with no regards of the length of these two vectors right?

Yes. `std::swap` for `std::vector` 's complexity is guaranteed to be constant time by the stardard:

23.3.6.3$10,11 [vector.capacity](bold by me):

> `void swap(vector& x);`
>   Effects: Exchanges the contents and capacity() of *this with that of x.
>   Complexity: **Constant time**.

And by $23.3.6.6/1 [vector.special], `std::swap` for `std::vector` is Specialized as:

> `template <class T, class Allocator>`
>   `void swap(vector<T,Allocator>& x, vector<T,Allocator>& y);`
>   Effects:
>    `x.swap(y);`

Here're some more explanations: [std::vector::swap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/swap) and [std::swap(std::vector)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/swap2)

> Exchanges the contents of the container with those of other. Does not
>   invoke any move, copy, or swap operations on individual elements.
>   All iterators and references remain valid. The past-the-end iterator is invalidated.
>
> Complexity :
>   Constant.

2. > It's just swapping pointers?

Basically, it depenes on the implementation of the STL you're using, but it is the most common way to achieve it.